# Multiple linear regression for real estate dataset prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I learned linear regression so I've decided to test it to this real estate dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Real+estate+valuation+data+set

I use gradient descend to calculate my weights but they not converge to optimum. If i set the learning rate to 0.01 and iterations equal to 100 I get nan and inf values and if I set the learning rate to something like 0.0001 it will not converge or I get nan and inf values.

```
import openpyxl
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

file = Path(r'C:\Users\Cata\Desktop', 'lini.xlsx')
file = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

fila = file.active

def Loss(x, w, y):
    pred = np.dot(x, w)
    m = len(y)
    return 1/(2*m) * np.sum(np.square(pred - y))

def dLoss(x, w, y):
    pred = np.dot(x, w)
    m = len(y)
    return  1/m * np.dot(np.transpose(x), (pred - y))

def Gradient(x, y ,learning = 0.000001, iterations = 1000):
    w = np.random.rand(7)
    m = len(y)

    for i in range(iterations):
        w = w - learning*dLoss(x,w,y)

    return w

x = []
y = []

for row in fila.iter_rows(min_row=2,max_row=400):
    acm = []
    acm.append(1)
    for i in range(1, 7):
        acm.append(float(row[i].value))
        #print(row[i].value, end=" ")
    x.append(acm)
    y.append(float(row[7].value))

y = np.array(y)

sa = Gradient(x,y)
print(sa)
test = [1, 2013.500, 6.5,   90.45606,   9,  24.97433,   121.5431]
print(test)
print(np.dot(test, sa))
```

Also i get this error

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  w = w - learning*dLoss(x,w,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is something you can do , first of all your formula for updating weight is not correct. try

```
w = w + learning*dLoss(x,w,y)
```

and take learning rate as 0.01 or 0.001(don't make learning rate too small), now it should converge.